# Need JQuery to Add a (None) or blank value to SharePoint Lookup Column

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, lookup-column

I have a Lookup column to another list but I need to display a "Blank" value or a "None" as the first item in the dropdown.  The column must remain "Required".  Does anyone have a JQuery example of how to do this?

Bismarck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
      $("select[title='look']").prepend("<option selected>none</option>")

   })

</script>
```

Tip:on-premise is different from online.The title of required look up column is "columnName Required Field" in SPO,you need to change it.

Comment: It works. Thank You